# Will PAnsiChar convert a Unicode string to a pointer of Ansi string?

Tags: delphi, unicode

I am using Delphi XE3.

I wonder whether PAnsiChar can convert a Unicode string to a pointer to Ansi string directly, as follows:

```
var
   AnsiMyString: AnsiString;
   MyString, MyString1: MyString;
   P1: PAnsiChar;
   P2: PChar;
begin
    MyString := “Test”;
    P1 := PAnsiChar(MyString);    -> Will this line convert a Unicode string to a pointer of Ansi String?

    MyString1 := P1;  -> Will this line convert a Ansi string to a Unicode string?
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer is in the emitted compiler warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> P1 := PAnsiChar(MyString);
> ```

This performs no conversion. The pointer contains the address of the UTF-16 data. Instead you need:

```
P1 := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(MyString));
```

Of course the compiler will bleat about the potential loss of data when converting from UTF-16 to ANSI. You should ask yourself very carefully why you are even contemplating this.

> ```
>  MyString1 := P1;
> ```

The ANSI text will be converted to UTF-16.

Comment: When will conversion from UTF-16 to ANSI cause data loss? I think the conversion is lossless.

Comment: ANSI strings only encode a subset of Unicode. Hence if the source string encodes code points not covered by the prevailing ANSI locale, they can't be converted. You'll see a substitution character, usually `?`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I have never noticed this in the past. I use the ATL and MFC string conversion macros frequently, see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx
So if Unicode to ANSI will cause data loss, then the macros in the above article, such as CW2A will also cause data loss, why MS has never mentioned such a problem in his document?

Comment: I guess it's just such a basic thing you are expected to know it. And MS keep their reference documentation terse. It seems like you might need to reconsider your approach to dealing with international text.